# Gelfand's fundamental representation theorem of C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

In Takesaki's 1967 article *A Duality in the Representation Theory of C ∗ -Algebras*,
he defines $H$ as the infinitely-dimensional Hilbert space such that every cyclic representation of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is a representation on a subspace of $A$ on $H$. He then goes on denote the set of all reps on $H$ as $\mathrm{Rep} (A: H)$. For an isometric operator $j: H \oplus H \to H$, he defines the $j$-direct sum of reps as $(\pi_1 \oplus_j \pi_2)(x) = j (\pi_1 (x) \oplus \pi_2(x)) j^{-1}$. For $\pi \in \mathrm{Rep} (A: H)$, define the orthogonal projection $p(\pi) : H \to \overline{\pi(A) H}$. Later on, the author defines the *admissible operator fields* as functions $x: \mathrm{Rep}(A: H) \to \mathcal{B}({H})$ such that:

- $x(u \pi u^* ) = u x(\pi) u^* $ for every unitary $u \in \mathcal{b}(H)$ and $\pi \in \mathrm{Rep}(A : H)$;
- $x(\pi_1 \oplus_j \pi_2) = x(\pi_1) \oplus_j x(\pi_2)$ for every pair $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in \mathrm{Rep}(A : H)$;
- $x(\pi) = p(\pi) x(\pi) p(\pi)$ for every $\pi \in \mathrm{Rep} (A: H)$;
- $x$ is bounded on $\mathrm{Rep}(A : H)$.

The author then claims that, due to "Gelfand's fundamental representation theorem of C*-algebras", **every continuous admissible operator field on $\mathrm{Rep}(A: H)$ for an abelian $A$ is of the form $\pi \mapsto \pi(a)$ for some $a \in A$.**

I'm curious which theorem the author is referencing? I'm familiar with the fact that for an abelian $C^*$-algebra we have a representation $A \to C_0 (\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a T2 locally compact space. How does that imply the bolded statement?

Every bit of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the topology on $\mathrm{Rep} (A: H)$ is the topology of pointwise convergence relative to *-strong topology on $\mathcal{B} (H)$.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the space of irreducible representations is exactly the spectrum, so that every continuous function on the space of irreducible representations comes from an element of the algebra?

Comment: But $\mathrm{Rep}(A: H)$ includes all representations, not just irreducible ones.

Comment: Yeah, but every nondegenerate representation is a limit of direct sums of irreducible ones, by Krein-Milman theorem. So presumably since you have that direct sum condition in the definition of admissible operator fields, such a map is necessarily determined by its restriction to irreducible ones? (Technically not the irreducible reps themselves since those are one-dimensional. But like those ones that are effectively one-dimensional, namely those with $p(\pi)$ being a rank one projection.)

Comment: I’ll admit I’ve never seen this definition before, so I’m just making an educated guess. You would need to actually check the details to see that the argument I gave actually works. But it seems at least reasonable to me.

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks for these comments. I'm curious though, why do irreps of abelian C*-algebras have to be 1-dimensional?

Comment: A rep is irreducible iff the only invariant subspaces are $0$ and $H$. If $A$ is abelian, and $\pi$ is an irrep, then this means the only projections in the commutant of $\pi(A)$ are $0$ and $1$. The commutant is a vNa, so it’s densely spanned by projections, so the commutant has to be $\mathbb{C}$. But $A$ is abelian, so $\pi(A)$ is abelian, so $\pi(A)$ is contained in its own commutant, so $\pi(A) = \mathbb{C}$. But then every operator on $H$ commutes with $\pi(A)$ and is thus in the commutant. But the commutant is  $\mathbb{C}$, so $H$ is 1-d.

Comment: @DavidGao Ok, I understand your argument now, thanks. Could you just elaborate some more on what "the limit of direct sums of irreducible representations" means? From googling, it seems that not every representation of a $C^*$-algebra can be written as a sum of irreps.

Comment: I meant the following sequence of facts: every rep of a $C^\ast$-algebras is a direct sum of zero representation and a non-degenerate rep; every non-degenerate rep is a direct sum of cyclic reps; every cyclic rep is the GNS rep associated with a state; convex combinations of pure states are dense in the space of all states; GNS reps of pure states are precisely the irreps; the GNS rep associated with a convex combination of pure states is a direct sum of the GNS reps of these pure states.